# Cross Multiplication in a Proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $h$:

$$\frac{h+z}{h} = \frac{a}{b}$$

I'm not sure how to simplify this with cross multiplication.

Comment: Is the left side $h + \frac{z}{h}$ or $\frac{h+z}{h}$?

Comment: $\frac {h+z}{h} = \frac ab$ or $h + \frac {z}{h}  = \frac ab$?  Formatting is important.

Comment: (h+z)/h  = a/b    sorry about that

Comment: Using MathJax could avoid confusion like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{h+z}{h} = \frac{a}{b}$$

$$\implies b(h+z) = ah$$

$$bh+bz = ah \implies bz = ah-bh \implies bz = (a-b)h \implies h = \frac{bz}{a-b} $$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides of the equation by $h$ and you get: $\\h^2-\frac{a}{b}h+z=0$ This should be easy to solve as it's just a quadratic.